# Finding the centroid of a polygon

Tags: c++, 2d, polygon, centroid

I use the following code to find the centroid of a polygon (I didn't write the code, it's from another question).

```
Point compute2DPolygonCentroid(const std::vector<Point> vertices) {
    Point centroid;
    double signedArea = 0.0;
    double x0 = 0.0; // Current vertex X
    double y0 = 0.0; // Current vertex Y
    double x1 = 0.0; // Next vertex X
    double y1 = 0.0; // Next vertex Y
    double a = 0.0;  // Partial signed area

    // For all vertices except last
    for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size() - 1; ++i) {

        x0 = vertices[i].x;
        y0 = vertices[i].y;
        x1 = vertices[i + 1].x;
        y1 = vertices[i + 1].y;
        a = x0 * y1 - x1 * y0;
        signedArea += a;
        centroid.x += (x0 + x1) * a;
        centroid.y += (y0 + y1) * a;

    }

    // Do last vertex separately to avoid performing an expensive
    // modulus operation in each iteration.
    x0 = vertices.back().x;
    y0 = vertices.back().y;
    x1 = vertices.front().x;
    y1 = vertices.front().y;
    a = x0 * y1 - x1 * y0;
    signedArea += a;
    centroid.x += (x0 + x1) * a;
    centroid.y += (y0 + y1) * a;

    signedArea *= 0.5;
    centroid.x /= (6.0 * signedArea);
    centroid.y /= (6.0 * signedArea);

    return centroid;
}
```

The problem is that it works ONLY when the points in the input vector `vertices` are in clockwise order. When the points are in counterclockwise order it doesn't work. Here's a picture of what I mean by cw && ccw order:

[image]

I don't understand why it doesn't work when just the order of the points change but the points are still the same.

Comment: As a minor code clarity change, you could just push a copy of the first vertex onto the back of the vector, so you don't need to special case that last operation.

Comment: I don't have the means to test the code right now, but I'm fairly certain that this algorithm should work with the points in either order (though the computed area will be negative). What does "it doesn't work" mean in this case? totally wrong centroid location?

Comment: @Rook Yes exactly, in case of ccw order i get a centroid outside of the polygon (totally worng).

Comment: I've just tested your code, and found that the result of the centroid calculation is exactly the same if I reverse the order of the vertices, as I'd expect. Can you provide some test data that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fc7be4a99262603

Comment: @Rook The only difference with my code is that my `Point` class has `uint32_t` `x` and `y`. Could this be a problem?

Comment: Yep, that would absolutely explain it. The first values assigned to `x` and `y` will be negative if you've got the wrong wind order, and assigning a negative value to an unsigned type will give you crazy numbers.

Comment: (and this should be a valuable lesson to all concerned about posting complete code with a compilable, executable example of the problem under discussion!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, as it turns out, is that `Point` had unsigned members. There's also a potential secondary problem, regarding floating point rounding issues.

In this algorithm, if the wind order is the wrong way around, the computed area will be negative, and when you do something like

```
centroid.x += (x0 + x1) * a;
```

you'll get an incorrect value because `a` will be negative and `centroid.x` is unsigned.

You should store the intermediate centroid values as a floating point of some kind, so that a) you won't get these signed/unsigned issues and b) so that you won't get rounding errors on every vertex; I'm not sure if these errors would end up being large enough to cause you problems, but it seems silly to risk it when it can be so easily avoided. You should cast to unsigned int (or whatever) at the very end when you return.